# Symbol's function definition is void: package-install-selected-packages

Tags: package, error

In order to install and remove packages automatically (which is especially useful when using Emacs for the first time on a new computer), I have the following lines in my `~/.emacs`:

```lisp
;; Specify required packages
(custom-set-variables
 '(package-selected-packages
   '( ;; Packages listed below
     fill-column-indicator
     )))

;; Load the package package
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)

;; Add package archives to list
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

;; Automatically install/uninstall packages
(package-install-selected-packages)
(package-autoremove)

;; Load package fill-column-indicator.el
(require 'fill-column-indicator)
;; Activate fill column indicator
(cond ((not fci-mode) (fci-mode)))
```

This usually works fine; however, on a couple of CentOS machines I have used this on now, upon starting Emacs I'm getting a second window with the message

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/<user name>/.emacs':

Symbol's function definition is void: package-install-selected-packages

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

If I remove the problematic line, I get a similar message complaining about `package-autoremove` instead, and if I remove that line too, I get the message `Cannot open load file: fill-column-indicator` in the minibuffer upon start and Emacs fails to load the file I told it to open from the terminal. And no matter whether I remove the two problematic lines, the package `fill-column-indicator` is not loaded (or at least isn't used).

Why do I get this error on these two machines, and what can I do to get rid of the error message and to make `fill-column-indicator` load?

Comment: Are the versions of `package.el` (or whatever file should define the missing function) the same on those machines? If not, that's likely your problem.

Comment: Do `C-x emacs-version` on a machine that works and a machine that does not and add the info to your question. FWIW, I would start with `emacs -Q` and do `(load-library 'package)` in the scratch buffer, then check if the function is defined with `C-h f  package-install-selected-packages`, i.e. simplify down to the bare essentials.

Comment: @NickD I think you mean `M-x emacs-version`? It's `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2021-08-05` on a machine that it works on and `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2020-04-03 on x86-01.bsys.centos.org` on the machines it doesn't work on.

Comment: @NickD There was a module for Emacs 27.1 on one of the computers which I loaded; that seems to get rid of the `Symbol's function definition is void` errors. Why? Now I'm getting `Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, fill-column-indicator` instead, though.

Comment: Yes, sorry: I misspoke. You should add the version information into your question, as well as your other comment. The question should contain *all* the relevant information.